# UIView outlet is nil when testing on device but works fine in the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

My setup is very simple. There is a ViewController (set as initial in the storyboard) which is loaded from a nib (the VC has no view, and the nib contains only a view). The view in the nib also has a view.

The code looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outputView: UIView! //ctrl-dragged from InterfaceBuilder

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.outputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
}
```

Here's the nib:

https://s17.postimg.org/dt3ivctkf/Screen_Shot_2015_07_22_at_15_59_54.png

[image: screenShot]

Everything works fine in the simulator (iPhone 6). The white view turns blue as expected. But when running on an actual device (iPhone 6 8.4 - the target is 8.4) Xcode throws a brick at me yelling that outputView is unexpectedly nil.

What do I do now?

**UPDATE**

Apparently this is a bug in Xcode 7. I've tried creating a new project on another computer and testing on a different iPhone and the result is exactly the same. I'll report it to bugreport.

Comment: This might not directly solve your question, but as of the latest operating systems, IBOutlets do not need to be weak. In fact, if you go through the latest WWDC videos of the past two years, apple advises against making them week.

Comment: I recommend deleting the view and readding it in the storyboard. Also create a new variable (with a different name) and hook it up. Sometimes IDE's get confused with their save states and what has changed and what not

Comment: The whole point of using XIB is to not use a storyboard (it is incredibly annoying when collaborating through Git). I have tried re-wiring the view and to no avail.

Comment: Thanks for positing this! I got exactly the same problem with XCode 7 and though I'm goin' nuts with this nil outlet.

Comment: Apple has fixed the problem with the latest beta.